# sum of values with same week of month

Tags: php

I have an array something like this:-

```
Array
(
    [2016-09-26] => 3
    [2016-09-24] => 1
    [2016-09-23] => 2
    [2016-09-22] => 1
    [2016-09-21] => 3
)
```

I want to add the value of same week. Desire output:-

```
Array(
    [0] => 7   // sum of 2016-09-21, 2016-09-22, 2016-09-23, 2016-09-24. these values belongs to same week
    [1] => 3   //sum of 2016-09-26 which is next week
)
```

Comment: Do you have dates of same year?

Comment: It may have different years data also.

Comment: You can probably use the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615861/get-week-number-in-month-from-date-in-php

Comment: Loop through the dates. Use this `date("W", strtotime($date_string)` and in the variable pass the dates one by one and then use if condition to check if week numbers are same or different. If are same then add up the values and push them to the array with the same key, otherwise push it with new key.

Comment: Check week number & year also in if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use year concatenated with kw for the key and sum the values with the same key.

```
$dates = array
(
    '2016-09-26' => 3,
    '2016-09-24' => 1,
    '2016-09-23' => 2,
    '2016-09-22' => 1,
    '2016-09-21' => 3
);

$result = array();
foreach ($dates as $date => $value){
    $key = intval(date("Y", strtotime($date)).date("W", strtotime($date)));

    if (!isset($result[$key])){
        $result[$key] = $value;
    } else{
        $result[$key]+= $value;
    }
}
rsort($result);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: your code works perfectly. Thank you so much sir. @mihutz

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think this will help you exactly with what you need.

```
$datewise_data = array
(
    '2016-09-26' => 3,
    '2016-09-24' => 1,
    '2016-09-23' => 2,
    '2016-09-22' => 1,
    '2016-09-21' => 3
);

$result = array();
foreach ($datewise_data as $date => $value){
    $key = date("Y-W", strtotime($date));
    //echo $key.'<br>';
    if (array_key_exists($key, $result)){
        $result[$key] += $value;
    } else{
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
 
// If you want result year-week pair wise ie. Array ( [2016-39] => 3 [2016-38] => 7 ) Then print it directly

// Can also use ksort() function if needed here
ksort($result); // ksort() function sorts an associative array in ascending order, according to the key
print_r($result);

// If you want results directly in values ie. Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 3 ) Then sort and print
rsort($result); // rsort() function sorts an indexed array in descending order.
print_r($result);
```