# WP_Query: Show posts in a certain order for a certain time

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I would like to display each post in the order specified under `post__in` on my home page for one day. That means first the post with ID 3 should be shown until 23:59:59, then the post with ID 1 for 24 hours until 23:59:59, then the post with ID 2 and so on. When all posts have been shown, it should start again from the beginning. Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

```
function post_of_the_day( $query_args) {
    global $post;
    
    $query_args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'example_post_type',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post__in'       => array(3, 1, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5)
        );

     return $query_args;

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one post per day of the week, you can make use of PHP's [`date() function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), with the `'w'` format string. It returns `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday, `6` for Saturday, etc. Then you can use that as an index to find the one post ID you want from your array, and use the `'p'` argument in your [`WP_Query()` arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters)

```
function post_of_the_day( $query_args ){
    $post_ids = array( 3, 1, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5 ); // List of available ID's
    $id_index = absint( date('w') );          // 0-6 based on day of the week

    $query_args = array(
        'p' => $post_ids[$id_index],          // 3 on Sun, 1 on Mon, 5 on Sat
        'post_type' => 'example_post_type'    // Your post type
    );
    
    return $query_args;
}
```

You shouldn't need to query all 7 posts with `post__in` if you just need the one. Generally, you want to try and retrieve as little information as necessary for speed, optimization, and ease-of-maintenance.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot! Can this also be applied to the weeks of a month or to the weeks of a year? So that not a post per day, but per week is shown? @Xhynk

Comment: Of course, anything you can get a number for. `date('n')` gets you the 1-12 number of the month, `date('W')` gets you the 1-52 number of the week (starts on mondays), and a bit more involved, but here's an answer for how to get ["current week of the month as a number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615861/get-week-number-in-month-from-date-in-php/32624747)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!